# Data.table conditional on list of columns

Tags: r, data.table

My code sample is below. I think it probably explains things better than I can. I get why this doesn't work--R perfoms the boolean operation on the column names, not the values in the columns, but I'm not sure how to make it work.

```
DT = data.table( a = 1:5,
                 b = 6:10,
                 a_valid = c(0,1,1,0,0),
                 b_valid = c(1,1,0,0,0)
)

# This works
DT[a_valid == 0, a := NA]

numeric_columns <- c('a', 'b')
binary_columns <- c('a_valid', 'b_valid')

# This doesn't.
DT[binary_columns == 0, numeric_columns := NA]
```

Comment: I want output that reflects this:

If a_valid == 0, a is NA.
 
If b_valid == 0, b is NA.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(numeric_columns)) {
  DT[get(binary_columns[i]) == 0, (numeric_columns[i]) := NA]
}
```

Which should be slightly faster with `set()`:

```
for (i in seq_along(numeric_columns)) {
  set(
    DT, 
    i = which(DT[[binary_columns[i]]] == 0), 
    j = numeric_columns[i], 
    value = NA_integer_
  )
}
```

Or switching to base R for a second:

```
setDF(DT)
DT[numeric_columns][DT[binary_columns] == 0] <- NA
setDT(DT)
```

Comment: No, I should have been more clear.I want output that reflects this:

If a_valid == 0, a is NA.
 
If b_valid == 0, b is NA.

Answer (score 1):

I would add to @sindri_baldur solution the possibility to use `lapply`:

```r
lapply(seq_along(numeric_columns), function(i) DT[get(binary_columns[i]) == 0, (numeric_columns[i]) := NA])
```

It will avoid the overhead of the `for` loops.

A little benchmark can be of help to choose the best solution

```r
library(data.table)

DT = data.table(a = 1:1e5,
                b = 1:1e5 + 1e5,
                a_valid = sample(c(0,1), size = 1e5, replace = TRUE),
                b_valid = sample(c(0,1), size = 1e5, replace = TRUE)
)
numeric_columns <- c('a', 'b')
binary_columns <- c('a_valid', 'b_valid')

dt2 <- copy(DT)
dt3 <- copy(DT)
dt4 <- copy(DT)
```

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  for (i in seq_along(numeric_columns)) {
    dt2[get(binary_columns[i]) == 0, (numeric_columns[i]) := NA]
  },
  lapply(seq_along(numeric_columns), function(i) dt3[get(binary_columns[i]) == 0, (numeric_columns[i]) := NA]),
  for(j in 1:2) {
    i1 <- which(dt4[[j]] == 0)
    set(
      dt4, 
      i = which(dt4[[binary_columns[i]]] == 0), 
      j = numeric_columns[i], 
      value = NA_integer_
    )
  }  
)

#       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#  9.962940 10.104035 11.278033 10.226006 10.555132  22.10373   100
#  4.453995  4.535093  7.726525  4.659652  4.830672 234.04730   100
# 11.781060 11.913439 13.056660 12.021012 12.365140  26.84604   100
```

The winner is the `lapply` solution in that scenario. If you need that kind of thing on more than two columns, the `set` solution will probably be better